# Android - How to handle multidimensional JSON results into a spinner using Volley library

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a listview of products displayed on my android app. I am using a web service that returns a JSON. Earlier I had only a flat list of products to display. But now for each list, I have to add a spinner with the `variants` values from JSON. How do I achieve this?

My present code gives me the below error

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 168 path $[0].variants`

Below is my code :

JSON response

```
{
"responce": "true",
"top_selling_product": [
{
"product_id": "10",
"product_name": "Palm Ruchi (Pack of 10)",
"product_name_arb": "",
"product_description_arb": "",
"category_id": "8",
"product_description": "",
"variants": [
{
"variant_id": "7",
"variant_name": "2L",
"in_stock": "0",
"price": "120",
"mrp": "130",
"unit_value": "25"
},
{
"variant_id": "8",
"variant_name": "5L",
"in_stock": "1",
"price": "240",
"mrp": "255",
"unit_value": "25"
},
{
"variant_id": "9",
"variant_name": "10L",
"in_stock": "1",
"price": "0",
"mrp": "0",
"unit_value": "0"
}
],
"product_image": "product-placeholder2.jpg",
"status": "",
"unit": "Box",
"increment": "0",
"rewards": "0",
"stock": "",
"title": "Oil"
},
{
"product_id": "11",
"product_name": "Sunflower Sunrich 1 ltr Box(pack of 10)",
"product_name_arb": "",
"product_description_arb": "",
"category_id": "8",
"product_description": "",
"variants": [],
"product_image": "product-placeholder3.jpg",
"status": "",
"unit": "Box",
"increment": "0",
"rewards": "0",
"stock": "",
"title": "Oil"
},
{
"product_id": "26",
"product_name": "TestName4",
"product_name_arb": "",
"product_description_arb": "",
"category_id": "8",
"product_description": "TestAddress4",
"variants": [],
"product_image": "img8",
"status": "",
"unit": "kg",
"increment": "1",
"rewards": "20",
"stock": "",
"title": "Oil"
}
]
}
```

Top_Selling_model.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class Top_Selling_model implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("product_id")
    @Expose
    private String productId;
    @SerializedName("product_name")
    @Expose
    private String productName;
    @SerializedName("product_name_arb")
    @Expose
    private String productNameArb;
    @SerializedName("product_description_arb")
    @Expose
    private String productDescriptionArb;
    @SerializedName("category_id")
    @Expose
    private String categoryId;
    @SerializedName("product_description")
    @Expose
    private String productDescription;
    @SerializedName("variants")
    @Expose
    private List<VariantsModel> variants = null;
    @SerializedName("product_image")
    @Expose
    private String productImage;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("unit")
    @Expose
    private String unit;
    @SerializedName("increment")
    @Expose
    private String increment;
    @SerializedName("rewards")
    @Expose
    private String rewards;
    @SerializedName("stock")
    @Expose
    private String stock;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductNameArb() {
        return productNameArb;
    }

    public void setProductNameArb(String productNameArb) {
        this.productNameArb = productNameArb;
    }

    public String getProductDescriptionArb() {
        return productDescriptionArb;
    }

    public void setProductDescriptionArb(String productDescriptionArb) {
        this.productDescriptionArb = productDescriptionArb;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public List<VariantsModel> getVariants() {
        return variants;
    }

    public void setVariants(List<VariantsModel> variants) {
        this.variants = variants;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getIncrement() {
        return increment;
    }

    public void setIncrement(String increment) {
        this.increment = increment;
    }

    public String getRewards() {
        return rewards;
    }

    public void setRewards(String rewards) {
        this.rewards = rewards;
    }

    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }




}
```

Variants_model.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class VariantsModel implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("variant_id")
    @Expose
    private String variantId;
    @SerializedName("variant_name")
    @Expose
    private String variantName;
    @SerializedName("in_stock")
    @Expose
    private String inStock;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("mrp")
    @Expose
    private String mrp;
    @SerializedName("unit_value")
    @Expose
    private String unitValue;

    public String getVariantId() {
        return variantId;
    }

    public void setVariantId(String variantId) {
        this.variantId = variantId;
    }

    public String getVariantName() {
        return variantName;
    }

    public void setVariantName(String variantName) {
        this.variantName = variantName;
    }

    public String getInStock() {
        return inStock;
    }

    public void setInStock(String inStock) {
        this.inStock = inStock;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getMrp() {
        return mrp;
    }

    public void setMrp(String mrp) {
        this.mrp = mrp;
    }

    public String getUnitValue() {
        return unitValue;
    }

    public void setUnitValue(String unitValue) {
        this.unitValue = unitValue;
    }

}
```

Top_selling_Adapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Config.BaseURL;
import Model.Top_Selling_model;
import gogrocer.tcc.R;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class Top_Selling_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Top_Selling_Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Top_Selling_model> modelList;
    ArrayList<String> variantsData = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
SharedPreferences preferences;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView product_nmae, product_prize;
        public ImageView image;
        public Spinner spinner;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            product_nmae = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            product_prize = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_prize);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
            spinner=(Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.variants);

        }
    }

    public Top_Selling_Adapter(List<Top_Selling_model> modelList) {
        this.modelList = modelList;
    }

    @Override
    public Top_Selling_Adapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_top_selling, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new Top_Selling_Adapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Top_Selling_Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Top_Selling_model mList = modelList.get(position);
         preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("lan", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language=preferences.getString("language","");
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(BaseURL.IMG_PRODUCT_URL + mList.getProduct_image())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.icon)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .dontAnimate()
                .into(holder.image);
      //  variantsData.add(mList.getVariants().getVariantName());
        Log.e("Top_selling_array",mList.getVariants().getVariantName());
        holder.product_prize.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.currency) + mList.getVariants().getPrice());
       // Log.e("Top_selling_array",mList.getVariants().toString());
        if (language.contains("english")) {
            holder.product_nmae.setText(mList.getProduct_name());
        }
        else {
            holder.product_nmae.setText(mList.getProduct_name_arb());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

}
```

Home_fragment.java

```
private void make_top_selling() {
        String tag_json_obj = "json_category_req";
        ArrayList<VariantsModel> variantsList = new ArrayList<VariantsModel>();
        isSubcat = false;
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("parent", "");
        isSubcat = true;
       /* if (parent_id != null && parent_id != "") {
        }*/

        CustomVolleyJsonRequest jsonObjReq = new CustomVolleyJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                BaseURL.GET_TOP_SELLING_PRODUCTS, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                        Boolean status = response.getBoolean("responce");
                        if (status) {
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Top_Selling_model>>() {
                            }.getType();
                            Type listType2 = new TypeToken<List<VariantsModel>>() {
                            }.getType();
                            top_selling_models = gson.fromJson(response.getString("top_selling_product"), listType);
                            top_selling_adapter = new Top_Selling_Adapter(top_selling_models);
                            rv_top_selling.setAdapter(top_selling_adapter);
                            top_selling_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.connection_time_out), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                retry,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        // Adding request to request queue
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

    }
```

CustomVolleyJsonRequest.java

```
public class CustomVolleyJsonRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomVolleyJsonRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomVolleyJsonRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

EDIT : Changed my POJO classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your models according to this JsonResponce.
Paste your json response here https://jsoneditoronline.org and see your formatted json and paste your json http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org here for creating your models. In http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org you have to choose Target language Java,
Source type Json, Annotation Style Gson and preview. Get your models from there and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have changed my POJO classes and was able to sort out the above issue. However, I still need to figure out how to populate those ```variants``` into a spinner. Can you help?

Comment: You need a spinner adapter for this. In your json response you have variants as a list for every product. You have to get values from this list and put it in your adapter. Here is a simple example of a spinner adapter https://mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: Hi @okan, How do I access the values from the JSON, for eg: In my Top_selling_Adapter.java

I have tried adding the Variants into an Arraylist using

```variantsData.add(mList.getVariants().get(position).getVariantName());```

But it gives me 

```java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0```

Comment: I think it is wrong because you have 3 variants for everyProduct. For this reason you have to make for loop for each variant list.

Comment: I have added another answer for you. You need to have 2 for loops. One for your mList. One for your variantList in member of mList.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (mList:mList){
   for (variant : Variants){
      variantList.add (variant)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @okan,

Can you help me by showing where do I add this in my Top_selling_Adapter.java.
I have not very well understood how to use this

Comment: Do you want to show all variants in one spinner ? Or you have more spinners for your listViews each item ? Which one

Comment: I have only one spinner per item. So, I want to show all variants for that item in the spinner.

Comment: Firstly create a String list. List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: If you guide me with the snippets which would generate the spinner. It would be really helpful.

Comment: @saishneugi i have added another answer for you which includes all code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a String list.

```
List<String> variantNameList = new ArrayList<String>();



for (mList:mList){
   for (variant : Variants){
      variantNameList.add (variant. variant_name)
   }
}
```

This is your list which icludes all variant names. Then you need an adapter

// Creating adapter for spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  variantNameList);
```

// Drop down layout style - list view with radio

```
buttondataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

// attaching data adapter to spinner

```
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Thats all

Comment: Hi @okan,
I am getting error for the for loop. I dont have any array with name ```Variants```.

It shows error saying ```Cannot resolve symbol Variants```.

I can access the Product name using ```mList.getProductName();```.

But not sure how to access the ```variants``` object within the array.

Comment: You have to get variants from your mList. mList.getVariants

Comment: This is what I have been trying

```for (mList:mList){
            for (variant : mList.getVariants()){
                variantNameList.add (variant.variant_name);
            }
        }
```

But it doesnt fetch the variants object. Not sure what I have been doing wrong

Comment: There is an adapter which includes your String ArrayList as variantNames. And there is an adapter which uses this list. Firstly you have to set your list into your spinner adapter then you have to set your adapter to your spinner. Thats all. I think you have to work making spinner without your project. Learn it and apply in your project

Comment: Did you try to debug it ? Be sure that you have json response from remote. You can be sure it with debugging or write your jsonResponse as a  log in to LogCat and check it

Comment: Yes, I get the response from the remote. I can access the Product name as

```mList.getProductName()```

But for variants I will probably have to first call ```mList.getVariants().getVariantName()```

But this is not working.

Comment: Do you have your variantNames in your jsonResponse ? Did yo see it

Comment: I get the same response as I have posted in my question above.
Main object is ```"variants": [
{
"variant_id": "7",
"variant_name": "2L",
"in_stock": "0",
"price": "120",
"mrp": "130",
"unit_value": "25"
},
{
"variant_id": "8",
"variant_name": "5L",
"in_stock": "1",
"price": "240",
"mrp": "255",
"unit_value": "25"
},
{
"variant_id": "9",
"variant_name": "10L",
"in_stock": "1",
"price": "0",
"mrp": "0",
"unit_value": "0"
}
],```

Comment: Have you checked the edits that I have made to my question with the updated model classes?
The ```variants``` is a private variable. I guess it wont be accessible in my adapter class. I would have to use the public method ```getVariants()```.
But not sure how to get the ```variant_name``` and other values from ```getVariants()```

Comment: I really appreciate your patience with this. I am was really frustrated finding out a solution to this. You have got me very close to the solution. Really appreciate.

Comment: You are welcome no problem. You have variants in your class private however your getter and setter methods public. For this reason this can't be a problem.

Comment: I think that the code I write above is the solution of your problem. You can create and set an adapter using this code. However we can not create your variant list. There is only one problem

Comment: yes, I only need to find a way to access my variants object. I am just not getting how to go about that.

Comment: I could not understand one think. You said you just want to show a spinner, only one spinner. However you want to do it in your recyclerView Adapter ? Why

Comment: This is how my code is implemented. Is it a problem with this way of implementation?

Comment: i think you have to create your variantList in your home fragment. Put your spinner in your home fragment layout. Make your loops in your home fragment onResponse method. Create your adapter and set your list here. You don't need your recyclerView adapter. Because you just want to make a spinner. You don't need this. I think it is the problem

Comment: Hi @okan, for that, I will have to change a lot of my code structure. Because this module has to be implemented throughout the entire application.